# Flutter application build failed and throwing Fatal Error ( Content is not allowed in prolog.)

Tags: flutter, gradle, fatal-error

I'm facing an issue after run the **Flutter Upgrade** once again on existing one. When I try to run my app I confronted the error that has given below.

**Error**

[Fatal Error] x86_debug-1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.pom:9:12: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.
> > Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f/x86_debug-1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :video_player_android
> project :app > project :wakelock
> > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.
> > Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-bd539267b42051b0da3d16ffa8f48949dce8aa8f.pom
> > An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I've tried every possible solution but couldn't find the right one.

**Most tried solution**

```
  allprojects {
repositories {
    ......
    maven {url "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io"}
}
```

}

Reffernce: [enter link description here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39729)

**Flutter Doctor log**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1415], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 2.10.3 at C:\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (11 days ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
• Engine revision bd539267b4
• Dart version 2.16.1
• DevTools version 2.9.2
```

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
X cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.22.0

[√] Connected device (5 available)
• Redmi Note 8 (mobile)       • 13ab130b      • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
• sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
• Windows (desktop)           • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1415]
• Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 84.0.4147.125
• Edge (web)                  • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 84.0.522.59

[√] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

> Note: Code run perfectly on Web version but issue arise when try to run on Emulator or physical device.

Any suggestion and solution on this issue would be appriciated.
Thanks.

Comment: check out this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61320#issuecomment-657559448

Comment: All of those has been tried by me but couldn't able to solve the issue in flutter latest (stable channel) version. But I have switched to master channel and it is working now. I have no clue about why it produced the such error in stable channel. Looking forward to know about it.

Comment: Oke, i think it is some flutter's issue and they fixed it in master.